# How to fix IndexOutOfBoundsException in Java Android App

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

Hi I'm trying to create an interactive Android quiz application in Java, and when I try to enter the quiz section I get an index out of bounds exception, does anyone know how to solve this?

I have tried to add in more questions to make sure the amount of questions is greater than 30 but it didn't work.

[image: error message]

> Main Activity Quiz Basics

```
package com.example.hp.demo;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.hp.demo.DbHelper.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.hp.demo.Model.QuestionBasics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivityQuizBasics extends AppCompatActivity {
    public int score = 0;
    public ArrayList<String> wrongQuestListBasics = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> selectedBasics = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> actualAnswerBasics = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<QuestionBasics> quesList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    int ctr1 = 1;
    QuestionBasics currentQ1;
    TextView txtQuestion1;
    RadioGroup grp;
    RadioButton rda1, rdb1, rdc1, rdd1;
    Button butNext1;
    Random random1 = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    TextView textViewTime1;
    int number;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    int progress = 1;
    String tableName = "", catName = "";
    TextView qstnNo;
    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions_basics);

        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this, "blah blah blah", null, 1);
        QuestionBasics myQuestion = new QuestionBasics(
                "What is note X?",
                "It's not a note",
                "A note that only xylophones can make.",
                "A note when a bowed instrument is played with two bows",
                "A synthesised x wave", "It's not a note",
                "Basics");


        mDBHlpr.addQuestionsBasics(myQuestion);


        List<QuestionBasics> mylist = mDBHlpr.getAllQuestions1(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_QUEST1, "doesnotmatter");
        for (QuestionBasics q : mylist) {
            Log.d("QUESTIONS", q.getQUESTION1());
        }

        qstnNo = findViewById(R.id.qstnNo);

        Intent iin = getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

        if (b != null) {
            tableName = (String) b.get("table_name");
            catName = (String) b.get("level_name");
            Log.d("Table Name", tableName);
            Log.d("Level Name", catName);
        }
        number = 0;
        //timer
        textViewTime1 = findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(1800000, 1000);
        timer.start();
        quesList1 = mDBHlpr.getAllQuestions1("questBasics", catName);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            while (true) {
                int next = random1.nextInt(50);
                if (!list.contains(next)) {
                    list.add(next);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //layout content
        currentQ1 = quesList1.get(0);
        txtQuestion1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        rda1 = findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rdb1 = findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rdc1 = findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        rdd1 = findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        butNext1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        setQuestionView();
        grp = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        butNext1.setEnabled(false);

        grp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                if (i == R.id.radio0 || i == R.id.radio1 || i == R.id.radio2 || i == R.id.radio3)
                    butNext1.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(30);
        progressBar.setProgress(1);
        //checking answer
        butNext1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progress = progress + 1;
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                RadioButton answer = findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                //Log.d("yourans", currentQ1.getANSWER1() + " " + answer.getText());
                if (currentQ1.getANSWER1().equals(answer.getText())) {
                    score++;
                    //Log.d("score", "Your score" + score1);
                } else {
                    wrongQuestListBasics.add(number, currentQ1.getQUESTION1());
                    selectedBasics.add(number, answer.getText().toString());
                    actualAnswerBasics.add(number, currentQ1.getANSWER1());
                    number++;
                }
                grp.clearCheck();
                butNext1.setEnabled(false);
                //finishing quiz
                if (ctr1 < 31) {
                    if (ctr1 == 30) {
                        butNext1.setText("End Quiz");
                    }
                    currentQ1 = quesList1.get(list.get(ctr1));
                    setQuestionView();
                } else {
                    timer.onFinish();
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void showResult() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityQuizBasics.this, ResultActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("scoreBasics", score);//Your score
        b.putString("section", "questBasics");//Your table name
        b.putString("category", catName);//Your category name
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("wrongQuestions", wrongQuestListBasics);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("selectedAnswer", selectedBasics);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("actualAnswer", actualAnswerBasics);
        intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void setQuestionView() {
        txtQuestion1.setText(currentQ1.getQUESTION1());
        rda1.setText(currentQ1.getOPTA1());
        rdb1.setText(currentQ1.getOPTB1());
        rdc1.setText(currentQ1.getOPTC1());
        rdd1.setText(currentQ1.getOPTD1());
        if (ctr1 < 10)
            qstnNo.setText("0" + ctr1 + "/30");
        else
            qstnNo.setText("" + ctr1 + "/30");
        ctr1++;
    }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            showResult();
        }
    }
}
```

> Database Helper

```
package com.example.hp.demo.DbHelper;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.example.hp.demo.Model.QuestionBasics;
import com.example.hp.demo.Model.QuestionChords;
import com.example.hp.demo.Model.QuestionScales;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Quiz.db";
    public static final String TABLE_SCORE = "score";
    public static final String SCORE_KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String SCORE_KEY_SECTION = "section";
    public static final String SCORE_KEY_CAT = "category";
    public static final String SCORE_KEY_SCORE = "score";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc"; //option c
    private static final String KEY_OPTD = "optd"; //option d
    private static final String KEY_CAT = "category"; //category
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "questScales";
    public static final String TABLE_QUEST1 = "questBasics";
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST2 = "questChords";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

//    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
//        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
//    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.db = db;

        String basicsTableCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST1 + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTD + " TEXT, " + KEY_CAT + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(basicsTableCreate);
        addQuestionsBasics(db);

        String scalesTableCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTD + " TEXT, " + KEY_CAT + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(scalesTableCreate);
        addQuestionsScales(db);

        String chordsTableCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST2 + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTD + " TEXT, " + KEY_CAT + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(chordsTableCreate);
        addQuestionsChords(db);

        String scoresTableCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORE + " ( "
                + SCORE_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + SCORE_KEY_SECTION
                + " TEXT, " + SCORE_KEY_CAT + " TEXT, " + SCORE_KEY_SCORE + " INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(scoresTableCreate);
    }


    private void addQuestionsBasics(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        QuestionBasics q101 = new QuestionBasics("What is pitch?", "The length of a sound", "The overall quality of a sound", "The highness or lowness of a sound", "The volume of a sound", "The highness or lowness of a sound", "B");
        this.addQuestionBasics(q101,db);
        QuestionBasics q102 = new QuestionBasics("What is 'timbre'?", "The ove", "format it", "compile it", "hardware it", "format it", "B");
        this.addQuestionBasics(q102,db);
        QuestionBasics q103 = new QuestionBasics("What is rhythm?", "The sound a metronome makes", "The organisation of music through time", "A beat that repeats itself", "The amount of beats in a bar", "The organisation of music through time", "B");
        this.addQuestionBasics(q103,db);
        QuestionBasics q104 = new QuestionBasics("What is harmony?", "A series of pitches creating a musical statement", "The result of multiple notes played simultaneously", "A strong match between 2 different notes", "The sound a chord makes when the notes are in the correct key", "A strong match between 2 different notes", "B");
        this.addQuestionBasics(q104,db);
        QuestionBasics q105 = new QuestionBasics("What is a 'melody'?", "A strong rhythm that keeps the tune going", "A series of pitches that form a musical statement", "A set of chords that works well together", "A short motif to transition 2 sections of a song", "A series of pitches that form a musical statement", "B");
        this.addQuestionBasics(q105,db);
        QuestionBasics q106 = new QuestionBasics("What is 'dynamics'?", "Changes in textures, such as switching instruments", "Variations in loudness and softness", "The movement of music between different keys", "The way the melody of a song integrates with the chords", "Variations in loudness and softness", "B");
        this.addQuestionBasics(q106,db);
        QuestionBasics q107 = new QuestionBasics("What two note note pairs have no sharp or flat between them?", "DE, AB", "DF, BC", "BC ,DE", "EF, BC", "EF, BC", "B");
        this.addQuestionBasics(q107,db);

    }
    public void addQuestionsBasics(QuestionBasics quest) {
        addQuestionBasics(quest,this.getWritableDatabase());
    }

    public void addQuestionBasics(QuestionBasics quest,SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION1());
        contentValues.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER1());
        contentValues.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA1());
        contentValues.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB1());
        contentValues.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC1());
        contentValues.put(KEY_OPTD, quest.getOPTD1());
        contentValues.put(KEY_CAT, quest.getCATEGORY1());
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_QUEST1, null, contentValues);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST1);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public List<QuestionBasics> getAllQuestions1(String tname, String lname) {
        List<QuestionBasics> quesList1 = new ArrayList<QuestionBasics>();
        String selectQuery1 = "SELECT  * FROM " + tname + " WHERE " + KEY_CAT + " = '" + lname + "'";
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                QuestionBasics quest1 = new QuestionBasics();
                quest1.setID1(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest1.setQUESTION1(cursor.getString(1));
                quest1.setANSWER1(cursor.getString(2));
                quest1.setOPTA1(cursor.getString(3));
                quest1.setOPTB1(cursor.getString(4));
                quest1.setOPTC1(cursor.getString(5));
                quest1.setOPTD1(cursor.getString(6));
                quesList1.add(quest1);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesList1;
    }

    public boolean insertScoreBasics(int scoreBasics, String tname, String cname) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(SCORE_KEY_SECTION, tname);
        contentValues.put(SCORE_KEY_CAT, cname);
        contentValues.put(SCORE_KEY_SCORE, scoreBasics);
        long resultscore = db.insert(TABLE_SCORE, null, contentValues);
        if (resultscore == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public int getScoreBasics() {
        Cursor c;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT MAX(" + SCORE_KEY_SCORE + ") FROM " + TABLE_SCORE + " WHERE " + SCORE_KEY_SECTION + " = '" + TABLE_QUEST1 + "' AND " + SCORE_KEY_CAT + " = " + "'I'";
        c = db.rawQuery(sqlSelectQuery, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int x = c.getInt(0);
        return x;
    }
}
```

> xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivityQuizBasics">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                android:background="@drawable/rect_background_pink">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/qstnNo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="01/30"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="05:00"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:max="30" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.03">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="@color/deeppurple"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:textColor="#fff" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the same way you fix it in any other app. You are trying to get the first element of an empty List/Collection/... first verify that the element exist, then fetch it

Comment: @edpor dont paste pics when posting errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
currentQ1 = quesList1.get(0);
```

change to

```
currentQ1 = quesList1.size() == 0 ? null : quesList1.get(0);
```

and add a protection

```
butNext1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          if (currentQ1 == null) {
             Log.e(TAG, "No questions in database!");
             return;
          }
      }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, doing this causes a null pointer exception,   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.hp.demo.Model.QuestionBasics.getQUESTION1()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.hp.demo.MainActivityQuizBasics.setQuestionView(MainActivityQuizBasics.java:171)
        at com.example.hp.demo.MainActivityQuizBasics.onCreate(MainActivityQuizBasics.java:106)

Comment: Do you know how I would fix this?

Comment: @edpor edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately I still get the error even with the protection implemented